# Java GUI Interface

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, interface

At the minute I'm creating a GUI which allows the user to add, remove, modify and update CV's which they get in from people. So in other words the GUI takes there name, email, years of experience, degree and so on. My question is how can I open the GUI outside Eclipse with out running Eclipse at all so the user can just click on the GUI on there desktop and interact with it.

If you could answer this it would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Export the jar file of your project and share the same jar to the user

Answer (score 2):

You can run executable JARs if you export them from Eclipse as "**Runnable JAR file**".
But first, you need to set up a *Running Configuration* for your project ([Context Menu] > Run As> Run Configurations...) where you need to define the class where is located the project's "main".
You also should package required libraries into the generated JAR but you need to make sure that, in the project's Properties -> Java Build Path all external libraries (except JRE System Library) are checked in the "Order And Export" Tab.

Then locate your generated jar in the file system and double click it to run.

Tip: if nothing happens, run it on the console using "java -jar [generatedFileName].jar" to check if the are exceptions being thrown.